# How do I exclude a (non-reframe) atom from re-frame processing e.g with o'doyle rule engine?

Tags: re-frame

Clojure: 1.10.0
clojurescript: "1.10.764
shadow-cljs "2.11.7"
re-frame "1.2.0"

I am creating a SPA using re-frame, and everything is working well. However, I recently watched a [video on o'Doyle rules engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27KuJU8r4-U)  and I thought it might be fun to try experimenting with this in my re-frame project. It creates a separate "facts table" in its own atom:

```
(ns cube-test.twizzlers.rules
 (:require
  [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
  [odoyle.rules :as o]))

(def rules
  (o/ruleset
    {::print-time
     [:what
      [::time ::total tt]
      :then
      (println "upate time rule:" tt)]}))

;; create session and add rule
(def ^:dynamic *session
  (atom (reduce o/add-rule (o/->session) rules)))

(defn update-time []
  (swap! *session
         (fn [session]
           (-> session
               (o/insert ::time ::total 100)
               o/fire-rules))))
```

I then created a button to activate the update:

```
[:button.user-action {:on-click #(re-frame/dispatch [::twiz.events/update-time])} "update time rule"]
```

The rule fires and everything works well, however I see a bunch of re-frame warnings on the console suggesting that re-frame is trying to hook and manage the Odoyle atom as one of it's own:

```
"twizzler.events.update-time: entered" cljs.core.js:168:20
upate time rule: 100 cljs.core.js:168:20
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "alpha-node", fqn: "alpha-node", _hash: 1411603897, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "beta-nodes", fqn: "beta-nodes", _hash: -674152665, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "last-id", fqn: "last-id", _hash: -1231616450, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "rule-name->node-id", fqn: "rule-name->node-id", _hash: -494456865, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "node-id->rule-name", fqn: "node-id->rule-name", _hash: 1615893599, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "id-attr-nodes", fqn: "id-attr-nodes", _hash: -1814751183, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "then-queue", fqn: "then-queue", _hash: 899186975, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
re-frame: no handler registered for effect: 
Object { ns: null, name: "then-finally-queue", fqn: "then-finally-queue", _hash: 2088468149, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 2153775105, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 4096 }
 . Ignoring. cljs.core.js:13285:10
```

"then-finally-queue" and "alpha-node" et. al are presumably o'doyle life cycle events on it's atom, and it looks like re-frame is trying to find handlers for them.

This question isn't really about making odoyle rule engine and re-frame work together, although if anyone has opinions about the plausibility of this scenario I'd be interested in hearing them (yes, there's an overlap between the frameworks, but I would regard the odoyle "fact table" as simply an alternate view that I would manage with re-frame subscriptions).

Anyhow, to make it clearer that this question isn't simply about odoyle, or an effect of odoyle's design, I created a generic atom like so:

```
(def ^:dynamic *a* (atom 10))

(defn update-atom []
  (swap! *a* inc))
```

and when I drive it, it generates:

```
"twizzler.events.update-dmy-atom: entered" cljs.core.js:168:20
Uncaught Error: No protocol method IMap.-dissoc defined for type number: 12
    cljs$core$missing_protocol https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/cljs.core.js:312
    cljs$core$IMap$_dissoc$dyn_41386 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/cljs.core.js:2213
    cljs$core$_dissoc https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/cljs.core.js:2224
    cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$2 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/cljs.core.js:6832
    re_frame$fx$do_fx_after https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.fx.js:40
    re_frame$interceptor$invoke_interceptor_fn https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.interceptor.js:216
    re_frame$interceptor$invoke_interceptors https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.interceptor.js:255
    re_frame$interceptor$execute https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.interceptor.js:365
    re_frame$events$handle https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.events.js:85
    re_frame$router$IEventQueue$_process_1st_event_in_queue$arity$1 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.router.js:580
    re_frame$router$IEventQueue$_run_queue$arity$1 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.router.js:325
    vec__42331 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.router.js:417
    re_frame$router$IEventQueue$_fsm_trigger$arity$3 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.router.js:459
    G__42328 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/re_frame.router.js:370
    NextJS 3
    day8$re_frame_10x$inlined_deps$re_frame$v0v12v0$re_frame$router$IEventQueue$_run_next_tick$arity$1 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.inlined_deps.re_frame.v0v12v0.re_frame.router.js:372
    vec__42751 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.inlined_deps.re_frame.v0v12v0.re_frame.router.js:478
    day8$re_frame_10x$inlined_deps$re_frame$v0v12v0$re_frame$router$IEventQueue$_fsm_trigger$arity$3 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.inlined_deps.re_frame.v0v12v0.re_frame.router.js:549
    day8$re_frame_10x$inlined_deps$re_frame$v0v12v0$re_frame$router$IEventQueue$push$arity$2 https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.inlined_deps.re_frame.v0v12v0.re_frame.router.js:363
    day8$re_frame_10x$inlined_deps$re_frame$v0v12v0$re_frame$router$dispatch https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.inlined_deps.re_frame.v0v12v0.re_frame.router.js:699
    day8$re_frame_10x$db$init_db https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.db.js:24
    day8$re_frame_10x$init_db_BANG_ https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.js:352
    <anonymous> https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/cljs-runtime/day8.re_frame_10x.preload.js:3
    globalEval https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/app.js:597
    evalLoad https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/app.js:1690
    <anonymous> https://localhost:8281/js/compiled/app.js:2162
app.js line 597 > eval:312:9
```

IOTW, re-frame is trying to "manage" this atom as well.

It looks like re-frame hooks *all* atom processing functions not just its own app-db ratom?

Is there a way I can mark an atom to exclude it from re-frame's hooks?  Or will I be forced to create a non-re-frame project to experiment with odoyle?  Note: odoyle has an [adapter for Rum](https://github.com/oakes/odoyle-rum), so it *can* work with other reactive frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding the superfluous messages:

This is an "answer" from the original poster.  Since I received no responses, I'll just explain what I discovered and how I dealt with the situation.  I do not claim to have any expert knowledge of re-frame beyond what I know as a basic user of the framework.

In looking at the source code for re-frame (which is amazingly quite small, and not very complicated BTW), [fx.cljs](https://github.com/day8/re-frame/blob/master/src/re_frame/fx.cljc) seems to be the source of all the messages I see.  I can see that in fact it has a lot of interceptors:

```
(def do-fx
  (->interceptor
    :id :do-fx
    :after (fn do-fx-after
```

After thinking about it, it makes sense that the hooking and intercepting is tied to the code and not to the atom i.e. you typically have one copy of the code loaded to deal with n atoms.

My main concerns about re-frame hooking my non-reframe atoms are twofold: performance and interference. As far as performance goes, this is just re-frame doing a simple check for a handler, not finding it, and printing a warning message.  Since state changes are at app level and not on the animation tick (my project is a Babylon.js 3d app), this is not a big issue.  Indeed, to add a lookup table of what atoms to monitor or not, while also not a big performance hit, would, if anything, decrease the performance even further.  So no big deal to have these messages.

I also realize that re-frame should not be interfering with the non-reframe atom at all.  Indeed, these messages are an indication that re-frame *is unable* to intercept the native atom.  So once again nothing to worry about.

So I was able to convince myself that these messages are really nothing to worry about.  However, the specter of having a lot of superfluous wordy message clogging up my console was annoying.

To deal with getting rid of all the messages, I made a call to re-frame's `set-loggers!` call, where I used a regex to filter the superfluous messages, something like:

```
(defn rf-odoyle-warn-override-logger [& args]
  (let [text (apply str args)]
    ; (prn "utils.rf-odoyle-warn-override-logger: text=" text)
    (if (re-matches #".*no handler registered for effect:.*Ignoring.*" text)
      (js/console.log "probable rf-odoyle interceptor no handler msg warning detected")
      (js/console.warn text))))
```

Invoked like this in my startup:

```
(re-frame.core/set-loggers!  {:warn utils/rf-odoyle-warn-override-logger})
```

Now, I just get one simple "collapsed" message in the console:

```
probable rf-odoyle interceptor no handler msg warning detected
```

### On using re-frame and o'doyle together:

vis a vis the viability of using o'doyle rules in re-frame, I see great promise for me since my main "view" is a babylon.js scene and not the DOM.  Thus I need to do a lot of game level logic outside of the DOM, where I think O-doyle will complement re-frame.  If your app is a basic Web app where the DOM is your main view, then I think it might feel kind of redundant to attempt to maintain odoyle state on top of the re-frame state (e.g. in app.db).